# Does 'array[i]=undefined' produce a sparse array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is `delete array[i]` the same as `array[i] = undefined`? I know that the former will produce a sparse array? Does the latter do the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the latter does not do the same, it just sets that index to the value `undefined`, it does not delete that index.

`delete` will delete the index, but will not update the length, so you end up with an index that is truly not defined, and doesn't just contain the value `undefined`.
In other words, a "sparse" array where the length is greater than the number of items.

You can test this easily with most array methods, as they will iterate over the value `undefined`, but not over indexes that aren't defined *(there's a difference)*

```js
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3];

delete arr[1]; // delete the second index

arr.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item); // 0, 2, 3
});

console.log('--------')

var arr2 = [0, 1, 2, 3];

arr2[1] = undefined; // set the second index to "undefined"

arr2.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item); // 0, undefined, 2, 3
});
```

Answer (score 1):

No, they don't do the same. From [MDN's `delete` operator article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Deleting_array_elements):

> **Deleting array elements**
>
> When you delete an array element, the array length is not affected. This holds even if you delete the last element of the array.
>
> When the `delete` operator removes an array element, that element is no longer in the array. In the following example, `trees[3]` is removed with `delete`.
>
> ```
> var trees = ['redwood', 'bay', 'cedar', 'oak', 'maple'];
> delete trees[3];
> if (3 in trees) {
>   // this does not get executed
> }
> ```
>
> If you want an array element to exist but have an `undefined` value, use the undefined value instead of the `delete` operator. In the following example, `trees[3]` is assigned the value undefined, but the array element still exists:
>
> ```
> var trees = ['redwood', 'bay', 'cedar', 'oak', 'maple'];
> trees[3] = undefined;
> if (3 in trees) {
>   // this gets executed
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

By using both one can make a dense array sparse or not. Their usage is different.

Let's see...

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
delete arr[10]; // <- returns true but arr is not sparse
delete arr[1];  // <- returns true and arr is now sparse

var arr = [1,2,3];
arr[1]  = undefined; // <- arr is not sparse
arr[10] = undefined; // <- arr is now sparse
```